# Laravel route called twice. [With HTTPS request]

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7, laravel-8, homestead

I am using Laravel **Homestead** with **NGINX**. So I have **one route** to perform a payment.
After **HTTPS request** to that **route** (**https:**//xxx.test/payment/capture), 
Laravel automatically processes **two requests** *one after the other*. 
So instead to have **one request** processed, I **have two** requests.

Why did this happen? 
I solved the problem by calling HTTP request (**http:**//xxx.test/payment/capture) instead of HTTPS and everything was as expected.

Comment: As of your question: `Why did this happen?`. Nobody has a clue. Please provide some code and we might be able to help you :)

Comment: @RobBiermann 

Hi Rob, this happened because I am a little stupid :) 
I don't have an Nginx configuration (because I don't know much about web servers) for SSL and whats happened? 

When I request https://xxx.test/payment/capture this requests came to the Laravel application (I don't know how) but after that I have another request HTTP://xxx.test/payment/capture (not secured request). I didn't know how to debug this because network tab shows only one request. So I debug this accidentally, I test it and it's work.

Hope that I better explain now :)